# Anything changed in AppScript Card Service? Empty buttons show up borders, etc

Tags: google-apps-script

Today I am seeing changes in my appscript cards,

1. Text boxes missing
2. Empty buttons are showing borders, etc
   I don't see any new release note(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases)

Comment: The problem seems to fix itself.